# Restore minimized app, OSX dock click event, pyqt, pyinstaller

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyinstaller

I compiled an app using pyinstaller (written in pyqt), everything works as expected except that if you minimize the app, it won't restore by clicking on the app dock icon. If you have unchecked the "**Minimize windows into application icon"** on the Dock preferences, then you can click on the document (not in the app icon) to restore it. I created a systray icon and I'm able to restore the app by clicking on it, although not to key on this. So, I'm not necessarily asking how to restore a minimized app, more on how to restore a pyinstaller compiled app after being minimized in mac. Or how to get the dock click event so I can call restore the app myself? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a [solution](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html), which works fine with [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html), please take a try if you still need:

```
root.createcommand('tk::mac::ReopenApplication', root.deiconify)
```